# Can GUID contain backslash (\)?

Tags: java

I want to know if it is possible for `GUID` to contain backslash (`\`).

I have not yet seen any case like this, but I just want to know.

I am using Java.

Comment: Probably depends on how the GUID is encoded. It is just a very large number, normally encoded in HEX, which means that it cannot contain special characters.

Comment: Where do you get your GUID?

Comment: @talex By using this `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`

Comment: [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) (which `java.util.UUID` supposedly implements) does not permit a backslash. Can you show us how you generated one and how you can tell it has a backslash?

Comment: @dave: He doesn't actually say that he saw one. He wants to make sure it can't happen.

Comment: @Henrik Good point - mis-read the question. So he should be safe then :)

Comment: @dave I can see in my `UUID` value equal sign `=`, So this sign is not special character, right?

Comment: `=` is not part of the specification so this would appear to be incorrect. Reviewing other comments, perhaps your UUID is Base 64 encoded?

Answer (score 2):

[Here you are](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) with the RFC about UUID.

Where it states the following:

> Each field is treated as an integer and has its value printed as a
>         zero-filled hexadecimal digit string with the most significant
>         digit first.  The hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are output as
>         lower case characters and are case insensitive on input. The formal definition of the UUID string representation is
>         provided by the following ABNF [7]:
>
> ```
>   UUID                   = time-low "-" time-mid "-"
>                            time-high-and-version "-"
>                            clock-seq-and-reserved
>                            clock-seq-low "-" node
>   time-low               = 4hexOctet
>   time-mid               = 2hexOctet
>   time-high-and-version  = 2hexOctet
>   clock-seq-and-reserved = hexOctet
>   clock-seq-low          = hexOctet
>   node                   = 6hexOctet
>   hexOctet               = hexDigit hexDigit
>   hexDigit =
>         "0" / "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9" /
>         "a" / "b" / "c" / "d" / "e" / "f" /
>         "A" / "B" / "C" / "D" / "E" / "F"
> ```
>
> The following is an example of the string representation of a UUID
>   as    a URN:
>
> urn:uuid:f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6

No `\` permitted then.

Answer (score 1):

Small clarification : what you see is a call to `toString()` for `UUID` which will transform the `128 bits` to something more human readable. That human readable part is only made from `abcdefABCDEF1234567890-` possible characters.

Comment: I can see in my `UUID` value equal sign `=`, So this sign is not special character, right?

Comment: @user3441151 can you show an example? that should not happen AFAIK

Comment: value is `UTTxNJ9cPE4Kv1E08TSfXA==` code is `java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Comment: That looks like base64 encoding (`=` is used for padding). Can you share the full code that produces this?